# Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Cache_Exception' with message > 'cache_dir must be a directory'

Tags: apache, zend-framework, error-handling, xampp

After doing my code update. I got this error.
Could you help me figure this one out?
I gave 777 permission to all of the folders.
Thanks in advance!

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Cache_Exception' with message
>   'cache_dir must be a directory' in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\mts\library\Zend\Cache.php:208 Stack trace: #0
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\mts\library\Zend\Cache\Backend\File.php(154):
>   Zend_Cache::throwException('cache_dir must ...') #1
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\mts\library\Zend\Cache\Backend\File.php(121):
>   Zend_Cache_Backend_File->setCacheDir('C:\xampp\htdocs...') #2
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\mts\library\Zend\Cache.php(152):
>   Zend_Cache_Backend_File->__construct(Array) #3
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\mts\library\Zend\Cache.php(93):
>   Zend_Cache::_makeBackend('File', Array, false, false) #4
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\mts\application\Bootstrap.php(22):
>   Zend_Cache::factory('Core', 'File', Array, Array) #5
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\mts\library\Zend\Application\Bootstrap\BootstrapAbstract.php(636):
>   Bootstrap->_initCache() #6
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\mts\library\Zend\Application\Bootstrap\BootstrapAbstract.php(589):
>   Zend_Application_Bootstrap_BootstrapAbstract->_executeResource('cache') 7#
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\mts\library\Zend\Application\Bootstrap\Boots in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\mts\library\Zend\Cache.php on line 208

Comment: Zend seems to think the `cache_dir` you set is not a directory, but most likely a file.

What value did you set as `cache_dir`?

Comment: 'cache_dir' =>'C:\temp\cache   I have created this folder because I had already tried to handle a problem in this way.

Comment: In that case something isn't being set right or passed correctly because in the stack trace I see `Zend_Cache_Backend_File->setCacheDir('C:\xampp\htdocs...')` so it looks like its trying to use something in `C:\xampp\htdocs` as the cache_dir, not `C:\temp\cache`

Comment: typical useless error message from zend without the path

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Setting the cache in bootstrap

```
  protected function _initCaching() {
        $frontend = array(
            'lifetime' => 7200,
            'automatic_serialization' => true
        );
        $backend = array(
            'cache_dir' => sys_get_temp_dir(), /**automatically detects**/
        );
        $cache = Zend_Cache::factory('core', 'File', $frontend, $backend);
        Zend_Registry::set('cache', $cache);
    }
```

Comment: It worked! This is a huge issue for a whole lot of people, and none have offered the answer. Thank you!

Comment: I am facing the same error can someone tell me that how to setup this function and in which file we place that function and where to call that function. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Go to C:\xampp\htdocs\mts\library\Zend\Cache\Backend\File.php at line 154 and `echo $value` before the conditions. It should give you a directory address. Make sure that directory exists in your file system. Basically you need to set this path correctly in your zend configuration.

Answer (score 3):

It's not about permission, ZF can't find the cache directory. Check if the directory you set in `application.ini` actually exists. 
As you are on `Windows` machine, permissions shouldn't be a problem.